# Why is the AutoCompleteExtender firing the Page_Load event instead of the service method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

So I'm trying to implement the AutoCompleteExtender tool from the AJAX Control Toolkit.

The following is the implementation of the AutoCompleteExtender on my ASPX page:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CustomerTextBox" CssClass="form-control" AutoComplete="off" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="CustomerTextBox"
    CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The Customer field is required." Display="None" />
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="CustomerAutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="CustomerTextBox"
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1" CompletionInterval="1000" 
    ServiceMethod="GetAllCustomerNames">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

This is the service method implemented in the code behind file:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static string[] GetAllCustomerNames(string prefixText, int count)
{

    List<string> allCustomerNames = new List<string>();
    List<Customer> allCustomers = GetAllCustomers();

    foreach (Customer customer in allCustomers)
    {
        if (customer.CustomerName.Contains(prefixText))
        {
            allCustomerNames.Add(customer.CustomerName);
        }
    }

    return allCustomerNames.ToArray();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I type a character into the text box the Page_Load event fires instead of the *GetAllCustomerNames* method. Could someone please help me find where I'm going wrong?

**Additional info:**

- I'm using Visual Studio 2013.
- This is a ASP.NET Web Form application running on .NET 4.5.
- I used the default style and template as when a new project is created and so a Master Page is being used.
- The *ToolkitScriptManager* is specified in the Master File and I have set *EnablePageMethods* property to true.

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Try [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] not WebMethod() and remove the next line.

You set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the TextBox, just delete AutoPostBack or set it to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but sadly removing it didn't work. I've updated my original post by removing the AutoPostBack property.

Comment: Also while I was searching for a solution, many said that the ScriptMethod attribute is necessary.

Comment: Maybe there is some interference with AutoComplete="off" of the TextBox. Try removing it, and also the RequiredFieldValidator, just to rule that out.

Comment: Also make sure that no Exception is thrown in your WebMethod. As a start simply return a hard coded dummy String Array.

Comment: Removing AutoComplete and the RequiredFieldValidator didn't make a difference unfortunately. Regarding the WebMethod, the issue I'm having is the method is not being fired so I can't check whether is any exception being fired from within.